# problem with my settings.json-file

Tags: latex-workshop

I'm not really familiar with the recipes in latex workshop so I always get an error in my settings.json-file while compiling. This is the content of my settings.json-file:

```
{
    "latex-workshop.view.pdf.viewer": "tab",
    "workbench.editorAssociations": [
        {
            "viewType": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb",
            "filenamePattern": "*.ipynb"
        }
    ],
    "json.schemas": [
    
    ]
    "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [

        {
            "name": "xelatex",
            "command": "xelatex",
            "args": [
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "%DOC%"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "biber",
            "command": "biber",
            "args": [
                "%DOCFILE%"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
       {
            "name": "xelatex -> biber -> xelatex*2",
            "tools": [
                "xelatex",
                "biber",
                "xelatex",
                "xelatex"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The error says "Expected commajsonc(514)". I'm pretty sure there is a recipe missing or I've got the wrong one. Does someone know this problem or sees where my mistake is?

Comment: I tried to remove the "json.schemas": [], and it worked for me:)

Comment: A comma is missing after `"json.schemas": [   ]`.

Answer (score -1):

Если случилась такая проблема проверь есть ли в файле "," за твоей строкой например:
**текст,
текст,
текст**
If there is such a problem, check if there is a "," in the file behind your line, for example:
**text,
text,
text**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).